# How do inject a property with Spring Framework .NET on a web service?

Tags: spring.net

I have a web service with a property that I would like injected by Spring Framework .NET.  There is no error message, and yet no injecting.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is what I have for the xml file:

```
  <object type="MyCompany.MyProject.Business.MyClass">
    <property name="PaymentService" ref="PaymentService" />
  </object>
```

Here is what I have for the code:

```
namespace MyCompany.MyProject.Web
{
    public class MyService : WebService
    {
        public IPaymentService PaymentService { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229800/how-can-i-get-my-spring-net-webservice-working ?

Comment: You configure a `MyClass` instance, but not a `MyService` instance, for one. Please provide a bit more context on what you're trying to achieve, and what kind of application this is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing.  We had to have an application context:

```
IPaymentService paymentService = (IPaymentService) SecurityHelper.GetAppContext().GetObject("PaymentService");

        public static IApplicationContext GetAppContext()
        {
            if (WebApplicationContext.Current == null) throw new Exception("Spring not initialized");
            IApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContext.Current;
            if (context == null) throw new Exception("Spring context not initialized");
            return context;
        }
```